# Microcontroller PIC32MX

Tags: microcontroller

If we are powering our PIC32 with a USB, why do we also need Vcc from an external power supply to provide to PIN8.
In my circuit I am powering the PIC32 with a USB, but when I check the value of voltage at the pin 8, it shows 0V. Shouldn't it show 3.3V ?

Comment: Could you provide the full microcontroller part number? There are literally hundreds of different microcontrollers in the PIC32MX line.

Comment: There are a number of peripherals that you need to power (and ground), so you can't just provide power through the VUSB pins. You need to regulate the 5V down to 3.3V and provide that (along with decoupling caps) on all the VCC/GND pins, not just the USB ones. Doing just the USB ones may exceed chip ratings and you risk burning out the chip. Not all the VCC pins are connected together, so you can't just pick a convienent pair and use those, you **must** use them all (even AVCC).

Comment: @NatsuKage The Pic32MX is 3.3V only, there are no 5V supply pins.

Comment: @Ron Beyer Yes, my bad. But the ICs of the PIC32 line are 5V tolerant on some pins. The IC still needs a 3.3V supply.  (refer to page 7 of http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/61156g.pdf )

Answer (score 2):

The VDD/VSS (VCC/GND) pins **must** be connected for the chip to work. These pins are not internally connected with each other in most cases, and they power different parts of the logic inside the chip (peripherals).

[Take a look at the data sheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/PIC32MX5XX6XX7XX_Family%29Datasheet_DS60001156K.pdf), this is for the PIC23MX5XX/6XX/7XX but they are the same for all PIC32MX families:

[image]

You must also use decoupling capacitors:

[image]

And here is the recommended **minimum** connections:

[image]

Additionally, you need to provide the chip with 3.3V only, so you need to use a voltage regulator to translate the 5V from USB to 3.3V for the power pins.

**Pay special attention to I/O** especially if it is powered via a different source. If you inject 3.3V into a 3.3V pin, **you will burn out the chip** when it is not powered. You can provide up to 3.2V into a 5V tolerant pin without burning it out, but any more than that will cause damage.

VBUS pin is an input that monitors the USB bus power, it **does not power the chip**. VUSB3v3 is a transciever supply, and should be connected to VDD if USB is not used, however **do not** provide more than 3.3V into this pin (as the name implies).

Comment: Typically the Analog input pins are not 5V tolerant, all other ones are, but yes, read the datasheet (carefully) before deciding how high to go on an input.

Comment: Deleted comment, my bad. That's indeed the case. You need to read the exact datasheet for each individual model. There's many different formats for the PIC32 family.